# How can I be notified only once of liveData change in different Fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have this piece of code where I am observing errorMessageData and accountViewModel is  viewModel
with Activity scope and I am observing it in different fragments I want to be notified only once 
for example if in FirstFragment I get notified about errorMessageData and then I navigate to 
SecondFragment I don't want to be notified again or it should be true for opposite case
If SecondFragment is in active state I do notified there about errorMessage change
I don't want to notified in FirstFragment when I navigate there.

```
accountViewModel.errorMessageData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
  message ->
  message?.let { Toast.makeText(context, it, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your LiveData object in a `ConsumableValue` like this

```
class ConsumableValue<T>(private val data: T) {

    private var consumed = false

    fun consume(block: ConsumableValue<T>.(T) -> Unit) {
        if (!consumed) {
            consumed = true
            block(data)
        }
    }
}
```

then in viewmodel

```
val foo = MutableLiveData<Consumable<Foo>>()
```

and in your fragment

```
viewModel.foo.observe(this, Observer { consumable ->
        consumable.consume {
            TODO()
        }
    })
```

Comment: cool solution although I think that google should provide some mechanizm like Behaviour and Publish processors in Rx

Comment: what is the difference between fun consume(block: (T) -> Unit){} and the one you used ?

Comment: Mine is a lambda with receiver so you can directly access T's methods and properties.